# Searching for data that can be in two different column (query/design)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Sorry if the title is not clear. I am a bit confused about how to plan my database schema as given my database design skill level the requirement falls under kind of advanced :) I could really use some help here. Anyway, here it goes ...

I need to track match details for teams. For the sake of simplicity, lets say I need to track the match date, result and the teams that played the match. Now, how do I design my tables so I can make sure all relevant data is returned without having to keep multiple records of the same match. I am not sure if I am explaining clearly, so here's an example below.

```
match_id    team1             team2    result
________    ________    ________     ________
1           Arsenal          Chelsea    5-3
2           Manchester Utd   Arsenal    1-0
3           Liverpool        Newcastle  2-0
4           Arsenal          Everton    1-0
```

From this data, if I search for match_ids for matches played by Arsenal, I should get the below results,
1,2,4.

Now, in the basic designs which I know of, I would normally search for matched in team name for the team name supplied and return the result. But here the team name can be in two different columns and both can be relevant. So, is it something I need to decide on the design level or something that can be done with some sort of query.

(Note: Storing teams as home/away is not an option for my requirement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just query both columns, it's not a problem:

```
select match_id
from matches
where team1 = 'Arsenal' or team2 = 'Arsenal';
```

(*You could also normalize this schema by placing teams in their separate table and leaving only their ids in the matches table, but that doesn't change much, you still have to query both columns. Read about database normalization, any SQL book covers this*).

Answer (score 1):

If there are always two teams per match, then I think you did a good job here, and when querying for a particular team, you'll want to search for one column OR the other (`SELECT match_id FROM matches WHERE team1 = "?" OR team2 = "?"`).

One note though: I would definitely split up the score into two columns:

```
match_id  team1           team2      score1  score2
________  ______________  _________  ______  ______
1         Arsenal         Chelsea    5       3
2         Manchester Utd  Arsenal    1       0
3         Liverpool       Newcastle  2       0
4         Arsenal         Everton    1       0
```

This way you'll be able to query on scores later on, if you need it. (e.g. Big wins = `SELECT match_id FROM matches WHERE ABS(score1 - score2) > 3;`)

The other option you have should be more scalable if there exists a possibility of having more than two teams per match. If this is the case, then you'd likely want to remove the uniqueness constraint on match_id and cut out the team/score columns from 2 to 1:

```
match_id    team            score
________    ________        ____
1           Arsenal         5
1           Chelsea         3
2           Manchester Utd  1
2           Arsenal         0
3           Liverpool       2
3           Newcastle       0
4           Arsenal         1
4           Everton         1
```

And of course, you're definitely going to want to take Sergio's advice in putting all this stuff into separate tables. "Teams" are likely going to have different attributes (hometown, coach name, etc.), and you're not going to want to duplicate that data.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the results you want but there may be a better design too.

```
Select * 
from table 
where (team1 = 'ARSENAL' or Team2 = 'ARSENAL')
```

You may want to Separate out scores such as Team1Score Team2Score otherwise you can't easily do math with them.

Answer (score 0):

for star I would not store the time name, I think its better if you store the times in other table and linq then thru an id.

And then you could create a table with columns id, match id and team id, and just search for the team id in that table!

Answer (score 0):

you can used this query and its no problem for your program:

select YOUR_ID_FIELDS
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME
where YOUR_FIELD_NAME(team1) = 'Arsenal' or YOUR_FIELD_NAME(team2) = 'Arsenal';

and for exmale (Chelsea)
select YOUR_ID_FIELDS
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME
where YOUR_FIELD_NAME(team1) = 'Chelsea' or YOUR_FIELD_NAME(team2) = 'Chelsea';